# vba if condition works fine but misbehaves when else statement is added

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have this code below.

```
Sub workbook_initialize()
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
        For i = 1 To Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If cell.Value >= Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 8).Value And cell.Value _
                 <= Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 11).Value Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell.Row, 10).Value = _
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next
End Sub
```

What the code does is loop through a particular range of cells in `Sheet1` and if any cell has value **greater than or equal to** value in `Sheet2 Column H` and at the same time **less than or equal to** the value of `Sheet2 Column K` on same row then make `Sheet1 Column J` same value as the corresponding cell in `Sheet2 Column C`, which works fine but when I add this line of code below, it doesnt yield the expected result.

```
 Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell.Row, 10).Value = "No Shift"
```

I'll appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: where exactly do you add this? Do you get an error?

Comment: i concur with ashleedawg: Plus, please explain what the "expected result" is and what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code flow and the description given, I assume you want to Check each value of Sheet1 Col E comes within in the limit defined by Sheet2 col H & K  and a corresponding token value indicating the matching range is to picked up from Sheet2 Col 3 and to be placed in Sheet 1 col 10. If sheet1 Col e value does not satisfy to any of the ranges within all the ranges listed in sheet 2 “No shift" is to be indicated.

With this code format it is better not to use `else` here since you have to complete the inner for loop to check all the limit values for testing the conditions and then only “No shift” condition be satisfied.

I tweaked your code a little. Please try

```
 Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, found As Boolean
    LastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
    found = False
        For i = 1 To Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If cell.Value >= Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 8).Value And cell.Value _
                 <= Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 11).Value Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell.Row, 10).Value = _
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
            found = True
            Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If found = False Then Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cell.Row, 10).Value = "No Shift"
    Next
```